# Translate API command line Quickstart is failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api

I would like to incorporate the Google Cloud Translate API into an application of mine, and I am following the command line tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart) to get in the hang of it; however, I am totally new to this platform and I am getting slightly overwhelmed, so I feel asking for direct help is a good option.

I followed that tutorial as exactly as I could understand, with a Windows x64 computer. I made a project dedicated to this, added the API to it, and got the JSON key. I then ran the environment variable command for the file path in Powershell.

When I was done with that, I ran the `curl` command shown in that page as well, but happens every single time I try to do this:

`Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type: application/json" value of type
"System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:20
+ curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -H "Authorizati ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`

What am I missing here? I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: You should update your question with the errors not post them in a picture in case the URL dies it will help no one in the future.

Comment: I tried to put code, is that good?